# High charts Issue with stock bar chart multiple line series

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng, angular2-highcharts

It's working fine when all data available but issue happens when we select range in bar at bottom in angular 11

I don't know why this issue generated?

Code in angular:-

```
var datas = [{
  data: [
    [1630175400000, 0],
    [1630089000000, 0.47],
    [1630002600000, -0.48],
    [1629916200000, 0.38],
    [1629829800000, 0.18],
    [1629743400000, 0.91],
    [1629657000000, 0.01],
    [1629570600000, -0.2],
    [1629484200000, 0.01],
    [1629397800000, -0.66],
    [1629311400000, 0.04],
    [1629225000000, -0.63],
    [1629138600000, 0.07],
    [1629052200000, -0.02],
    [1628965800000, 0],
    [1628879400000, 0.24],
    [1628793000000, -0.45],
    [1628706600000, 0.21],
    [1628620200000, -0.04],
    [1628533800000, -0.34],
    [1628447400000, -0.08],
    [1628361000000, 0.03],
    [1628274600000, -0.23],
    [1628188200000, 0.29],
    [1628101800000, -0.19],
    [1628015400000, 0.2],
    [1627929000000, -0.13],
    [1627842600000, -0.06],
    [1627756200000, 0.02],
    [1627669800000, -0.36]
  ],
  id: "base1",
  name: "Avg. growth rate",
  type: "line"
}, {
  data: [
    [1628533800000, 117.442863],
    [1630175400000, 117.476804],
    [1630089000000, 117.476804],
    [1630002600000, 116.930384],
    [1629916200000, 117.488726],
    [1629829800000, 117.039701],
    [1629743400000, 116.834498],
    [1629657000000, 115.777653],
    [1629570600000, 115.764878],
    [1629484200000, 115.996878],
    [1629397800000, 115.988679],
    [1629311400000, 116.764601],
    [1629225000000, 116.7125],
    [1629138600000, 117.458283],
    [1629052200000, 117.377938],
    [1628965800000, 117.395677],
    [1628879400000, 117.395677],
    [1628793000000, 117.116852],
    [1628706600000, 117.64148],
    [1628620200000, 117.392843],
    [1628533800000, 117.442863],
    [1628447400000, 117.841829],
    [1628361000000, 117.933245],
    [1628274600000, 117.902974],
    [1628188200000, 118.170114],
    [1628101800000, 117.826993],
    [1628015400000, 118.045463],
    [1627929000000, 117.811225],
    [1627842600000, 117.968985],
    [1627756200000, 118.045426],
    [1627669800000, 118.024255]
  ],
  id: "base2"
  name: "IN (GBP)"
  type: "line"
}]
```

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live example with the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zwsLxyac/

You have unsorted data which causes Highcharts error #15: https://assets.highcharts.com/errors/15/

You need to sort your data before it is passed to a chart:

```
datas.forEach((series, index) => {
    series.data.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]);
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0nuezd8b/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.data